Quasi-particle decay in Fermi Liquids Involving Matsubara Sums
My course notes had a part to calculate the decay rate of fermi particle using the second order terms in the self-energy operator which contain an imaginary part and hence can be used to calculate the life time of the particles.
The above diagrams give the sum (V(q) = V(0))$$-\frac{|V(0)|^2}{\beta^2L^6}\sum_{k',q} G_{0}(k-q)G_{0}(k')G_{0}(k'+q)$$ and after performing the matsubara summations we get the expression 
Now I have tried to do the matsubara summation and my expressions look nothing like this, they have bosonic distribution terms resulting from poles containing the frequency term. My question is whether this expression is correct and if so, whether anybody knows a source where this is properly calculated as I am struggling to understand some of the finer details regarding this part of the topic.

Please do not use images/screenshots for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage/equations using MathJax.

Perhaps your Matsubara calculation is wrong, but we cannot judge it by what is included in the question...
